# Unable to login to harbor using Docker cli, failed with status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: docker, harbor

We have setup harbor(v2.2.1) on AWS ECS.
We are able to login into Harbor portal with default admin/Harbor12345 credentials.
However when we try to login to harbor from docker using below command, we are getting **"Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://harbor.company.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized"**.
***Command: docker login https://harbor.company.com***

When we check the harbor core logs, it says that **"failed to authenticate harbor_registry_user: Failed to authenticate user, due to error 'Invalid credentials'"**

Note: We have changed below harbor service URL's to our company specific URL's. (eg: **https://harbor-jobservice.company.com**)
(core, registry, jobservice, registryctl, portal, trivy-adapter)
We are using AWS RDS and AWS Redis.

We can even see the Trivy-Adapter health check as Passed on Harbor Portal. (meaning harbor services are able to communicate internally.)

Comment: Did you find the solution meanwhile? Hitting the same error.